# Classification: one of the classes have a much wider range of predictor values then others.

Tags: classification, multi-class

How do I supposed to deal with the situation when one of the classes is very general, it actually covers a bunch of classes, but other 3 classes I have are very precise. I have a data that has a lot of classes, I just need 3 of them, and I use 4th class as a class for everything else. What problems such method of labeling can cause and how do I deal with those problems? Thank you!

My data has about 170 features and I have about 1500 samples. I plan to use Random Forest classifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With 170 features and only 1500 examples, I'd be worried about overfitting. So make sure you use a validation set and use some kind of regularization if performance on the training and validation sets differs much.
But regarding the classes, you seem to have 4 classes and care about the distinction between each pair of classes, so using classification with 4 classes seems like the right choice.
One thing you could consider is if that 4th class actually consists of 2 or 3 clearly distinct irrelevant classes, you could classify those. So if your data consists of 5 classes and you threw 2 together because you don't care about those 2, you could try classifying the 5 classes. Giving the algorithm 5 more distinct classes might work better than 4 classes of which 1 is more complicated because it is the combination of 2 classes. However this is highly problem domain specific. If you don't have clearly defined subclasses for that 4th irrelevant class, splitting it isn't going to help you.

Comment: Thank you! I set a maximum depth of a tree to 8 to avoid over fitting, and it works good.